# Google Analytics Tracking Facebook Like

Tags: google-analytics, facebook-like

I am trying to track when users Facebook Like my page via Google Analytics. I am using a Google Analytics Debugger extention which reports my GA Event firing properly. I am thinking that I have either not set up my Google Analytics account properly, or am looking in the wrong place in Google Analytics.

I have implemented several `_trackEvents` for non-social tracking which I am able to see in Google Analytics when I go into the Real-Time -> Events panel. For tracking social media items, I am using `_socialEvent` instead. I do not see Google Analytics capturing this data when I go to the Real-Time -> Events panel.

I want to note that I am testing on my dev environment which Facebook/Google cannot see. I am wondering if this makes a difference?

Google Analytics Debugger Output:

```
_gaq.push processing "_socialEvent" for args: "[facebook,follow,https://my-dev-environment.com/]":
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not showing up in real-time reporting because it's not an event - it's a social interaction :) If you're seeing the _socialEvent coming through the debugger, that is good. You can view Social Interactions in Acquisition > Social > Plugins. If you're socialEvents are working, they'll show up here. Doesn't take too long (10 minutes or less... usually) to show up. Keep refreshing.

[image]

Comment: Are you able to help me implement this on my website please? I'm not seeing anything in my Plugins report in GA despite trying to add the JS to our pages. I've added this JS: http://www.enterf1.com/wp-content/themes/NativeChurch-child/js/ga_social_tracking.js - here is an example page: http://www.enterf1.com/british-grand-prix/where-to-sit-at-silverstone. I would highly appreciate any help!